# Kendoui grid is not working in IOS 7

Tags: kendo-grid

**Kendoui Grid is not working in IOS 7**, *especially in binding data from remote*.
It fetches the value from remote URL, but it is not displaying in the grid.
If we do some other operation in grid like **paginating, adding or deleting rows.. etc**, then it displays data.

Comment: Any luck with a fix for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently due to a rendering bug in iOS7.

Telerik have a workaround for this [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/web-ui-grid-display-problem-in-ipad-safari-%28ios-7-%29)